# Concatenating multiple columns within a row in a single column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

**Background:**
I am working on Sql2000 query where I need to get a cross tab query report. I tried few combinations and got the results using RollUP.

**Issue**
The real problem is that I have to insert the records in a table which has only one column. 
For instance: 
My actual records (after RollUP) have 3 columns and are as follow:
ID|May|Jun|Total

CS|21 |54 |75
AB|12 |15 |27

(These results are coming in grid format)

The problem I need to insert in them in a table having only 1 column. Format would be

Data

ID     May     Jun     Total     
21     54     75
12     15     27

Please note that column header is also inserted in the second table. 
Does this makes sense?
I know this can be done easily with reporing services or crystal reports but I have limiation of not going for them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you want to do is concatenate the strings of the three (or four?) columns into one?

I'll save you the bad practice lecture that usually accompanies this type of question:

Based on your example, I am assuming you want fixed length fields, and not delimited ones.  If you want delimited, use varchar instead of char and put delimiting strings in between.  The last column is cast as varchar since you don't need the extra padding.

```
SELECT CAST([ID] AS char(10)) 
   + CAST(May AS char(10)) 
   + CAST(June AS char(10)) 
   + CAST([Total] AS varchar(10)) AS column1
FROM ...
```

This would result in

```
CS        21        54        75
AB        12        15        27
```

Comment: Yes, I need the similar solution but the problem is that the columns are dynamic. The first table I mentioned is coming from a dyanmic SQL query. SET [AT]SQL=' SELECT [Date] =COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Date],105),''TOTAL''),'+ [AT]SQL= + ' [NET]=SUM(ISNULL(Amt,0)) FROM tblBase B INNER JOIN #tempMASTER T ON T.ID= B.ID GROUP BY [Date] WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY GROUPING([Date])' 


@SQL contains the list of Months, I want to display. It also depends on certain criteria.

PS: replace [AT] with @

Comment: Also, I need to have the column header as well from the first table.
How to get that one?

Comment: It did not work exactly but yes it did gave me an idea to get closer to the solutions.

Thanks Daniel.